# Python.. Can't get my mistake

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a program for my class so we can calculate easy network's subnet mask, private blocks and a lists of id,broadcasts etc. When I do some tests I get an error `" unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method'` and `'builtin_function_or_method'` ". So far I found out that I get this error when code is working with powers of 8.

```
usInputSubnet = input("How many subnets does your network have?: ")
inputSubnet = int(usInputSubnet)

dunamh = 1
while inputSubnet > (2 ** dunamh) - 2:
    dunamh += 1

usInputMaxHost = input("How many Max Host does your network have?: ")
inputMaxHost = int(usInputMaxHost)

dunamh1 = 1
while inputMaxHost > (2 ** dunamh1) - 2:
    dunamh1 += 1

sunoloDunamewn = dunamh + dunamh1

dunamhSubnet = dunamh
count = 0
while dunamhSubnet >= 8:
    dunamhSubnet -= 8
    count += 1

if sunoloDunamewn >= 25:
    Class = 'Non exist'
elif sunoloDunamewn >= 17:
    Class = 'A Class'
elif sunoloDunamewn >= 9:
    Class = 'B Class'
elif sunoloDunamewn >= 1:
    Class = 'C Class'
else:
    Class = "GTP"

if dunamhSubnet == 1:
    id = 128
elif dunamhSubnet == 2:
    id = 64
elif dunamhSubnet == 3:
    id = 32
elif dunamhSubnet == 4:
    id = 16
elif dunamhSubnet == 5:
    id = 8
elif dunamhSubnet == 6:
    id = 4
elif dunamhSubnet == 7:
    id = 2
elif dunamhSubnet == 8:
    id = 1

bytes = [0, 128, 192, 224, 240, 248, 252, 254, 255]

idVar = id
idVarStr = str(idVar)

if Class == "A Class":
    if count == 0:
        firstByte = str(255)
        secondByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
        thirdByte = str(0)
        forthByte = str(0)
        subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
        for ID in range(inputSubnet):
            print ('10.' + idVarStr + '.0.' + '0')
            idVar += id
            idVarStr = str(idVar)
    if count == 1:
        firstByte = str(255)
        secondByte = str(255)
        thirdByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
        forthByte = str(0)
        subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
        for ID in range(inputSubnet):
            print ('10.' + '0.' + idVarStr + '.0')
            idVar += id
            idVarStr = str(idVar)
    if count == 2:
        firstByte = str(255)
        secondByte = str(255)
        thirdByte = str(255)
        forthByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
        subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
        for ID in range(inputSubnet):
            print ('10.' + '0.' + '0.' + idVarStr)
            idVar += id
            idVarStr = str(idVar)
elif Class == "B Class":
    if count == 0:
        firstByte = str(255)
        secondByte = str(255)
        thirdByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
        forthByte = str(0)
        subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
        for ID in range(inputSubnet):
            print ('172.' + '16.' + idVarStr + '.0')
            idVar += id
            idVarStr = str(idVar)
    elif count == 1:
        firstByte = str(255)
        secondByte = str(255)
        thirdByte = str(255)
        forthByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
        subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
        for ID in range(inputSubnet):
            print ('172.' + '16.' + '0.' + idVarStr)
            idVar += id
            idVarStr = str(idVar)
else:
    firstByte = str(255)
    secondByte = str(255)
    thirdByte = str(255)
    forthByte = str(bytes[dunamhSubnet])
    subnetMask = (firstByte + '.' + secondByte + '.' + thirdByte + '.' + forthByte)
    for ID in range(inputSubnet):
        print ('192.' + '168.' + '0.' + idVarStr)
        idVar += id
        idVarStr = str(idVar)

print ("Class: " + Class)
print ("Subnet Mask: " + subnetMask)
```

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself instead of as pictures.  You can use the [edit] link.

Comment: please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updating my code here now

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. Your code currently raises `NameError`, due to being non-consistent with capitalization. Can you show at least smallest amount of effort and show us actually **runable** code? Learn more on how to provide [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry for being young and stupid :/ I corrected it now

Comment: Hint: when `dunamhSubnet` may be equal to 0 and what happens when it does?

Comment: That was my second mistake i see. It shouldn't reach 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a name `ID`, but later on misspell it `id`, which happens to be the name of a builtin function in Python. Additionally, you set a different variable `idVar` to also point to `id`. That's why you get the `unsupported operand type(s)` error, as you're trying to add the `id` function to itself.

My suggestion would be to rename your variables to something like `input_subnet` or similar—variable names in Python are lowercase by convention and should be speaking for themselves.

Comment: But the problem occurs only when my subnet power is 8 or 16. When code works with other powers, it works like a charm.

Comment: Honestly I didn't read through your whole code as it's kinda hard to follow. But not using `id` (or any other builtins) as a variable name will definitely prevent the specific error you mentioned.